# How to crete this type of array through using of Loop?

Tags: php

This is my Array:

```
$data['mytest'] = array(
                    array(
                    'title' => $mytest[0],
                    'heading' => 'My Heading',
                    'message' => $my[0],
                    ),
                    array(
                    'title' => $mytest[1],
                    'heading' => 'My Heading',
                    'message' => $my[1],
                    )
                );
```

How to create this type of array through using of Loop?

Comment: [check how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's difficult to say, without knowing what $mytest and $my are.

Comment: `foreach($mytest as $key => $value) { $data['mytest'][] = ['title' => $value, 'heading' => 'My Heading', 'message' => $my[$key]]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$d1 = array();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  array_push($data, array('title' => $mytest[$i],
                          'heading' => 'My Heading',
                          'message' => $my[$i],)
            );

}
```

Now

```
$data['mytest']  = $d1
```

Here , we are basically pushing the sub-arrays in main array and then will assign the array created to `mytest`